# Storing large amounts of simulated time series data

Tags: java, database, dictionary, simulation, time-series

I am looking for a way to store large amounts of simulated time series data for later processing. A data point can be described by a mapping from String to a tuple of primitive data types (mostly floating point). Each data point has a time series and each time series has an id. I am looking for an efficient way to write/read this data to/from disk. The simulation roughly looks like this

```
Sample sample = new Sample();
for (int i=0; i<samplesize; i++) {
   State s = initialState();
   for (int t=0; t<stages; t++) {
      Map<String,Double> data = s.getData();
      sample.add(i,t,data);
      s = s.nextState();
   }
}
```

To implement the Sample class, I have so far tested the following

- Nested lists / key-value map: Quite straightforward, but keeping all data in memory and then serializing everything to disk does not scale well.
- MapDB: I have tested two variants, (a) using the time series id as key and a time series as value, (b) using a flat index of time series id and time index as key and a data point as value. I am a little worried about the performance of (b), but (a) worked reasonably well.

I have also considered simply writing everything into a CSV. The upside of this is that virtually anybody could import the data later on. The downside is that searching for a particular time series or record with an arbitrary id would require reading the file line by line until the record is found.

Comment: Mapdb is a good thing - see if this http://kotek.net/blog/3G_map helps you in tweaking a bit more to achieve better performance

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using external memory, you may want to read through the chapter on B-trees in [Henrik Jonsson's thesis](http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/udbl/Theses/HenrikAndreJonssonPhD.pdf) - [B-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) themselves are a very popular way to index data in external memory and you should be able to find implementations in Java, and Jonnson discusses how to adapt them to store time series data.

Comment: I'd rather look for a ready-to-go library before making the effort in implementing (and testing) my own b-tree. I think MapDB also uses a b-tree for its BTreeMap. But thanks for the link to the thesis.

Answer (score 0):

A ready-to-go (open source) library is the [Hierarchical Data Format](https://www.hdfgroup.org/) (HDF) which can be used to store time series data. A [Java-compatible version](https://support.hdfgroup.org/products/java/) of the software also exists.

Internally it uses B-trees to store data as well as providing many other features to improve performance (compression, caching etc).